# Given length and number of digits,we have to find minimum and maximum number that can be made?

Tags: dynamic-programming

As the question states,we are given a positive integer **M** and a non-negative integer **S**. We have to find the smallest and the largest of the numbers that have length **M** and sum of digits **S**.

**Constraints:**

(S>=0 and S<=900)

(M>=1 and M<=100)

I thought about it and came to conclusion that it must be **Dynamic Programming**.However I failed to build **DP state**.

**This is what I thought**:-

**dp[i][j]=First 'i' digits having sum 'j'**

And tried to make program.This is how it looks like

```
/*
  *** PATIENCE ABOVE PERFECTION ***
    "When in doubt, use brute force. :D"

    -Founder of alloj.wordpress.com
```

*/

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define pb push_back

#define mp make_pair

#define nline cout<<"\n"

#define fast ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false),cin.tie(0)

#define ull unsigned long long int

#define ll long long int

#define pii pair<int,int>

#define MAXX 100009

#define fr(a,b,i) for(int i=a;i<b;i++)

vector<int>G[MAXX];


int main()
{
    int m,s;

    cin>>m>>s;

    int dp[m+1][s+1];

    fr(1,m+1,i)

     fr(1,s+1,j)

       fr(0,10,k)
          dp[i][j]=min(dp[i-1][j-k]+k,dp[i][j]); //Tried for Minimum

    cout<<dp[m][s]<<endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

Please guide me about this DP state and what will be the time complexity of the program.This is my first try of DP.

Comment: no need for dp here, it's greedy algorithm

Comment: Exactly Greedy is a better approach here, just find the number with this property and sort the digits increasingly or decreasingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
dp solution goes here :-

#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

int dp[102][902][2] ;
void print_ans(int m , int s , int flag){
    if(m==0)
        return ;
    cout<<dp[m][s][flag];
    if(dp[m][s][flag]!=-1)
        print_ans(m-1 , s-dp[m][s][flag] , flag );
    return ;
}
int main(){
    //freopen("problem.in","r",stdin);
    //freopen("out.txt","w",stdout);
    //int t;
    //cin>>t;
    //while(t--){
    int m , s ;
    cin>>m>>s;
    if(s==0){
        cout<<(m==1?"0 0":"-1 -1");
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i <=m ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<=s ;j++){
            dp[i][j][0]=-1;
            dp[i][j][1]=-1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        dp[1][i][0]=i;
        dp[1][i][1]=i;
    }
    for(int i = 2 ; i<=m ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j<=s ; j++){
            int flag = -1;
            int f = -1;
            for(int k = 0 ; k <= 9 ; k++){
                if(i==m&&k==0)
                    continue;
                if( j>=k && flag==-1 && dp[i-1][j-k][0]!=-1)
                    flag = k;
            }
            for(int k = 9 ; k >=0 ;k--){
                if(i==m&&k==0)
                    continue;
                if( j>=k && f==-1 && dp[i-1][j-k][1]!=-1)
                    f = k;
            }
            dp[i][j][0]=flag;
            dp[i][j][1]=f;
        }
    }
    if(m!=0){
        print_ans(m , s , 0);
        cout<<" ";
        print_ans(m,s,1);
    }
    else
        cout<<"-1 -1";
        cout<<endl;
//  }
}
```

Comment: here print_ans function is used to print ans .

Answer (score -1):

The DP state is (i,j). It can be thought of as the parameters of a mathematical function defined in terms of recurrences(Smaller problems ,Hence sub problems!)

More deeply, 
State is generally the number of parameters to identify the problem uniquely , so that we always know on what we are computing on!!

Let us take the example of your question only

Just to define your problem we will need Number of Digits in the state + Sums that can be formed with these Digits (Note: You are kind of collectively keeping the sum while traversing through digits!)

I think that is enough for the state part.

Now,

Running time of Dynamic Programming is very simple.

First Let us see how many sub problems exist in a problem :

You need to fill up each and every state i.e. You have to cover all the unique sub problems smaller than or equal to the whole problem !! 
Which problem is smaller than the other is known by the recurrent relation !!

For example:
Fibonacci Sequence

```
F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)
```

Note the base case , is always the smallest sub problem .!!
Note Here for F(n) We have to calculate F(n-1) and F(n-2) , And it will reach a stage where n=1 , where you need to return the base case!!
Hence the total number of sub problems can be said as all the problems between the base case and the current problem!

Now, 
In bottom up , we need to process each and  every state in terms of size between this base case and problem!

Now, This tells us that the Running time should be

**O(Number of Subproblems * Time per each subproblem).**

So how many subproblems exist in your solution DP[0][0] to DP[M][S]
and for every problem you are running a loop of 10

O( M*S (Subproblems ) * 10 )

Chop that constant of!
But it is not necessarily a constant always!!

Here is some code which you might want to look! Feel free to ask anything !

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
bool DP[9][101];
int Number[9][101];
int main()
{
    DP[0][0]=true;  // It is possible to form 0 using NULL digits!!
    int N=9,S=100,i,j,k;
    for(i=1;i<=9;++i)
        for(j=0;j<=100;++j)
        {
            if(DP[i-1][j])
            {
                for(k=0;k<=9;++k)
                    if(j+k<=100)
                        {
                            DP[i][j+k]=true;
                            Number[i][j+k]=Number[i-1][j]*10+k;
                        }
            }
        }
    cout<<Number[9][81]<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You can rather use backtracking rather than storing the numbers directly just because your constraints are high!

`DP[i][j]` represents if it is possible to form sum of digits using i digits only!!

```
Number[i][j]
```

is my laziness to avoid typing a backtrack way(Sleepy, its already 3A.M.)

I am trying to add all the possible digits to extend the state.

It is essentially kind of forward DP style!! You can read more about it at [Topcoder](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/;jsessionid=A3B5B330B7B07FE3A36856984D56AA82?module=Thread&threadID=700080&start=0&mc=9#1899829)

Comment: Note, if you downvote tell me  the  reason plus OP has asked at the last for this rather than the problem!!

Comment: thanks for your effort :) Can you please demonstrate me how does the state look like in this question.Thanks again

Comment: dp[i][j]=First 'i' digits having sum 'j' in your language directly

Comment: Actually, your thought process was correct but I fear your transitions are wrong + you have defined the state correctly but you forgot to mention what it tells us! 
The correct definition will be is it possible using i digits to make a sum of j !!
I will rather add some code for the same